# AccessDenied: Required claim values are not provided when accessing education/users endpoint

Tags: json, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I'm unable to access the `education/users` endpoint but I am able to access other endpoints (`education/classes`, `education/schools`).

Whenever I try to get a list of all users, I get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AccessDenied",
        "message": "Required claim values are not provided.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "58c42204-440a-482c-b1e9-4c65bb413ed1",
            "date": "2018-03-21T20:23:24"
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to make the call using the Graph Explorer, I'm given the following notice:

> Failure - Status Code - Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions.

Unfortunately, I get the same error after modifying my permissions.

If anyone has any idea why this might be happening, I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: What permissions did you modify?  Have you re-consented the application with admin consent endpoint after that?

Comment: From within my application, I set `ENV['OAUTH_SCOPE'] = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All ' \
  'https://graph.microsoft.com/Directory.Read.All ' \` (this was my attempt to grant the highest level of access to the application). Then I tried to grant permissions from the tenants side: the Microsoft Active Directory >> Enterprise Applications >> APP >> Permissions, but no options were available. Even using the Graph Explorer, while logged in as a tenant's admin with all the permissions selected under **modify permissions**, I was unable to call /v1.0/education/users.

Comment: @WayneYang-MSFT: Using the Microsoft Graph Explorer as the admin of a school, I should be able to access /education/schools/{id}/users or education/users, right? I can access individual users through /education/schools/{id}/users/{id}, but I can't seem to get a list of _all_ users. Maybe I'm using the wrong endpoint?

Comment: The permissions that you should add is `EduRostering.ReadBasic` . And you should modify permssions at Microsoft Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For app+user (delegate) permissions, the only supported scope for the `/education/users` collection on MSGraph is `EduRoster.ReadBasic`.

This supports getting an individual user's information, or information on lists of users within classes of which you are a member, but does NOT support browsing the entire set of users in a tenant, as it is deliberately a restricted scope.

If you need more than this, you would need to use app-only permissions, and sync the users into your own data store with `EduRoster.Read.All`, which would allow you to get all of the users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since I found reference to both (and I may be conflating two sets of permissions), I won't edit your response, but I believe the scope is `EduRoster`, as opposed to `EduRostering`.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is - we changed the name shortly before release, so I often confuse the two. Edited.